# Image saved says invalid image. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, png, blob, filesaver.js

I have been trying to save a div element as image using domtoimage.js and filesaver.js. The image is saving fine but there's nothing in it. Says the image is invalid.

```
var image = domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('form')); 
var blob = new Blob([image], {type: "image/png"});
saveAs(blob, 'myimage.png');
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows this example, meaning that the toBlob function returns a promise so you must use `then`.

```
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('my-node'))
  .then(function (blob) {
    window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
  });
```

So your code should become

```
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('form'))
  .then(function (blob) {
      window.saveAs(blob, 'myimage.png');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried the above way and it works in computers and android devices. However, in ios (safari/chrome) its not working. From what I understand its supposed to open the image in a new window? But it just doesnt do that. The reason I tried my original code is because it successfully opens a new window in ios (safari/chrome) and but doesn't display any image, just a small box. Any idea on how to get the image to open in new tab in ios?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. IOS is pretty restrictive when you save files from the web. Also on the domtoimage github page it say that they dont support Safari. You must investigate this further. There may be a workaround.